# Call a function then reverse arguments of the same function and call again

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt4

I was wondering if this was possible in one function:

```
def test(x, y):
    print(x, "+", y)
```

When I call test, I want to call test(1, 2) followed immediately by test(2, 1).

This is inside of a QPushButton.clicked.connect so it needs to be a callable.
I tried a list comprehension of

```
[x for x in [test(1, 2), test(2, 1)]]
```

and I'm getting a weird output that I can't explain.

```
1  +  2
2  +  1
[None, None]
```

Is there any lambda I can do to do that or would that be unpythonic?

For now I just made a secondary function but I think this is kind of ugly.

```
def press_test(x,y):
    test(x,y)
    test(y,x)
```

*Edit* I should add that I have multiple functions that test(y,x) should follow:

```
def test2(x, y):
    print(x, y)

def press_test2(x, y):
    test2(x,y)
    test(y,x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common idiom in PyQt when connecting signals like this, is to use a `lambda` with default arguments:

```
    self.button.clicked[()].connect(
        lambda x=1, y=2: (self.test(x, y), self.test(y, x)))
```

There are a couple of things to note here. Firstly, the `[()]` selector is necessary because otherwise `clicked` will send a boolean argument by default, which would clobber the first argument of the lambda. Secondly, the function calls have to go in a tuple (or equivalent), because `lambda` can only contain a single expression (omitting the parentheses will give an error).

**UPDATE**:

Some signals have several overloads that send different values.

For example, the [QButtonGroup.buttonClicked](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qbuttongroup.html#buttonClicked) signal can send either an int or button. To select a specific overload, you would do either:

```
    buttongroup.buttonClicked[int].connect(handler)
```

or:

```
    buttongroup.buttonClicked[QAbstractButton].connect(handler)
```

In PyQt, you can also omit the selector, in which case a default overload will be used (which happens to be the second one in the above example).

However, there are some signals (like QPushButton.clicked and QAction.triggered) which have a default argument *value*. That is, the C++ signature looks like this:

```
    void clicked (bool = 0)
```

In PyQt, this effectively means there are *two* overloads: one which always sends a boolean value, and one which doesn't. The default overload is the one that *does*. So in order to explicitly select the one that *doesn't*, you have to pass in an empty tuple, i.e:

```
    button.clicked[()].connect(handler)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.  Can you either explain the [()] or give me something to look up for what this actually does?

Comment: @Faller. I've updated my answer with an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use *args along with itertools:

```
from itertools import permutations

def press_test(*args):
    all_args = permutations(args)
    for arglist in all_args:
        test(*arglist)
```

BTW, you don't really want to use a list comprehension here... a list comprehension like

```
[f(x) for x in list]
```

is really only useful if f(x) returns a value. If f(x) is just going to do something, the for loop is (usually) faster. Since f(x) only 'does something' and doesn't return a value, you will get a list full of `None` as you noticed, that you are just going to throw away. You can use `timeit` to verify the relative speed of the methods.

Comment: I was trying to do it without having a "press_test" function.

Answer (score 0):

A general approach would be:

```
[yourMethod(*arg) for arg in itertools.permutations(args)]
```

In this case, `args` represents `(1,2)`.  Of course if you don't need these is a list, simply use the same approach without the list comprehension...